# epoch vs date object for web services

Tags: javascript, java, rest, validation, date

Not sure if a long debate is required to finalize one between `epoch` & `date object` as input for RESTFul web-services. I can list down advantages of both: 
***Advantages of `epoch`***:

- Less confusing: Timezone conversion is not required
- As it is a number, validation is easy

***Disadvantages of `epoch`***:

- On 32 bit values, date range is just 136 years (can we refer after that? And, now a days, 64bits has wider range)

***Advantages of `date object - ISO 8601`***:

- Don't have to care too much about date range limitations

***Disadvantages of `date object - ISO 8601`***:

- Request payload should be validated (string should be parsed and verified if it is valid date object)
- Time zone should be specified & conversions are required while using

There should be more than these. I would like to hear from you on this.

Thanks

Comment: 32 bit processors are not limited to 32 bit values. But this question is not on topic for SO as it's too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks! But, I believe, Opinion based on experience is valuable information

Comment: It's not a matter of what you believe, these are just the rules of the site. Take a look at the help section about what is on topic.

Comment: @Navaneeth As pvg is trying to say, Stack Overflow is designed to avoid long drawn-out unresolved discussions. Your own opening clause is a sign this Question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can google/bing for "date time best practices" for more info such as using UTC (contrary to your statement about zones).

Comment: The ECMAScript time value (your "epoch") has a range of approximately ±274,000 years from 1970. There is no "ISO 8601 Date object", and exchanging ISO 8601 format strings with zero offset (i.e. "UTC") is common. Parsing is simple and timezone issues easily accommodated.